# How can we disable AWS Alarms for Serverless warmup functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

We're using Serverless to automate deployments of AWS lambdas and step functions.  Amongst others, we use the following plugins:

- serverless-plugin-warmup
- serverless-plugin-aws-alerts

As a result we have alarms not only for the functional lambdas but also for each warmup category (office-hours, outside-office-hours) per function per alert type (errrors, throttles etc).

In order to reduce costs, we'd like to disable alerts for the warmup functions.

Having read the docs for serverless-plugin-aws-alerts, there doesn't seem to be a way to disable alerts for a function that is defined outside the given serverless file.

Is the only approach to globally disable all alerts, but then enable per function per alart?  Stating the obvious, this will result in significant config change

Thanks

We read the `serverless-plugin-aws-alerts` docs and code as we hoped for a way to specify a pattern to disable alerts for a given set of functions, eg `-warmUp`.